# Is there any reason to return true here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this type of structure appears in most of the javascript files in my project. My question is, is there a reason to return true after setElements and calling it in an "if" statement like so :

```
App.ModuleName.setElements = function() {
    App.ModuleName.el = {
        title: $("#title")
    }
    return true;
};


App.ModuleName.init = function() {
    if (App.Common.checkDependency('ModuleName')) {
        if(App.ModuleName.setElements()) {
            //do something
        }
    }
};
```

as opposed to removing the return true and just doing :

```
if (App.Common.checkDependency('ModuleName')) {
    App.ModuleName.setElements();
    //do something;
}
```

?

Comment: not in this case but there could be a reason for it that we can't see.

Comment: Do other methods in your module return Errors, throw Errors, return error codes, return false on error, etc? This could be here only for parity across methods, for policy or historical reasons.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Not really, no, perhaps this was this initial intent though. It was written by consultants at the beginning of the project.

Comment: They may have been paid per line of code

Comment: The code testing for success could have been written before the `setElements` method and presumed `setElement` might need to test for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code provided, it is not necessary.  Given that context, your version of the code is superior for clarity.

But you really have to see all usages of a function in the project to determine whether or not it could be refactored.

Imagine a situation where you are doing some kind of SQL transaction, but there are operations that have to be completed OR rolled back which are not part of the SQL transaction.

```
App.OtherModuleName.init = function() {

    bool elementsWereSet = false;

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(model);

    try {
        // Do some processing
        DoSomething(model, transaction);

        elementsWereSet = App.ModuleName.setElements();

        DoSomethingElse(model, transaction);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        transaction.rollBack();

        if (elementsWereSet) {
            manuallyRollBackElements();
        }
    }
};
```

Note that `elementsWereSet` will be `false` if an exception is thrown anywhere before when `setElements` returns `true`.

If an exception occurs, the bool will determine if you have to manually roll back anything.

There are other ways of accomplishing this dynamic, but I will say I have used this pattern at least once in a major piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you detailed, there is no reason to return true.  I suspect it's just a coding convention of the contractors you used to develop the code.  It's likely their practice to be able to validate that the calls succeed, and on more complicated calls it's not a bad idea.